# Как отключить сообщение типа [main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils в IJ IDEA 2022.3.2

Tags: testng

При написании теста с использованием TestNG версия 7.7.0 в консоли вываливается сообщение [image: [main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Running:] Как это можно убрать?

мой pom.xml